# Shaka Player + Mux.js on live streaming on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-streaming, hls.js, shaka

I have been trying to implement live streaming on Shaka Player. Normal `Hls.js` is working fine, but I can't seem to implement it with Shaka Player it shows `error code 4030`.

Pure Hls on React:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video-main')
const streamSourceUrl = 'https://cdn-mxs-01.akamaized.net/Content/HLS/Live/channel(02d97239-cf8c-abac-8549-afd56a0b3924)/index_L2.m3u8?hdnts=st=1590987868~exp=1590991468~acl=/*~hmac=611ab22b64269b296e4c1a3572b91f5d011805c2e69339bb216a2d273d2f561f&ticket=IucGX1FZuEF3w4YBUIn8MYsdhdoBafV-Baox-nIrViUqI3cpJh4KE7O-lW6TD4oWrxBjmEkTgmLYGyGO5vqKY-cfI1w00trRkVy5Ea30Snb_0emE7s5hycyjg1lDdCTXmIBpKMjXgy1vLQC_Y9u6eG4yUEh8EO-NcEqq6LpDZKMobVVxE-NQz2r2VTH9J5DqFfxcG5_6PaZbAUqRRB6A6XjCCsLH4aK7ET1ce7RmqDlrf1EEYOoUzuHBgTvGa2scw_Rg9_8='

if (Hls.isSupported()) {
  let hls = new Hls()
  hls.loadSource(streamSourceUrl)
  hls.attachMedia(video)
  hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
    video.play()
    that.setState({
      isPlaying: true,
      isError: false,
    })
  })
}
```

Shaka Player on React, `mux.js` has been imported on my `index.html` similar to [shaka demo](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/blob/master/demo/index.html)

```
const streamSourceUrl = 'https://cdn-mxs-01.akamaized.net/Content/HLS/Live/channel(02d97239-cf8c-abac-8549-afd56a0b3924)/index_L2.m3u8?hdnts=st=1590987868~exp=1590991468~acl=/*~hmac=611ab22b64269b296e4c1a3572b91f5d011805c2e69339bb216a2d273d2f561f&ticket=IucGX1FZuEF3w4YBUIn8MYsdhdoBafV-Baox-nIrViUqI3cpJh4KE7O-lW6TD4oWrxBjmEkTgmLYGyGO5vqKY-cfI1w00trRkVy5Ea30Snb_0emE7s5hycyjg1lDdCTXmIBpKMjXgy1vLQC_Y9u6eG4yUEh8EO-NcEqq6LpDZKMobVVxE-NQz2r2VTH9J5DqFfxcG5_6PaZbAUqRRB6A6XjCCsLH4aK7ET1ce7RmqDlrf1EEYOoUzuHBgTvGa2scw_Rg9_8='

const video = document.getElementById('video-main')
const player = new shaka.Player(video)
player
  .load(streamSourceUrl, 0)
  .then(() => {
    // I am expecting the stream to load like Hls code above
  })
```

Error log:
[image: error log]

Comment: Versions
shaka-player: 2.5.11
mux.js: 5.6.3